# How to retrieve image along with other data from back end and display on the screen using hibernate, spring mvc and angular js?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, hibernate

I'm using hibernate, html, spring mvc and angular js for my application. From hibernate I'm constructing the view model which is going to bind with the front end html page. For uploading and saving I have no trouble. But while retrieving the same image from DB using hibernate I'm only receiving a byte array. How to get the file component inside "tab.namePRAttch"(see the code below).

How to get the file from byte [] as the same one which I uploaded?

The java code where the byte array component is mapped to view model is given below. I have used byte[] as the image datatype.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
Set<NamePageAttchModel> atchList = result.get(i).getNameAttachments();
        List<byte []> attbyArr = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        for(NamePageAttchModel m : atchList){
            byte [] a = m.getAttachFile();
            attbyArr.add(a);
        }
        viewModel.setNamePRAttch(attbyArr);
```

```js
$scope.retrieveName = function() {
    if (SearchService.getAdvflagNm()) {
      $http({
          params: {
            "mainId": $scope.mainPR.mainInfoId
          },
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'namePage/retrieveNamePge'
        })
        .then(
          function mySuccess(response) {
            $scope.showSuggestions = false;
            $scope.disOthrSec = false;
            if (response.data !== "" && response.data !== undefined) {
              $scope.namePageTabs = response.data;
            }
            SearchService.setAdvflagNm();
            if (response.status == 500) {

            },
            function myError(response) {});
        }
    };
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="file" ng-image-model file-model="tab.namePRFile" multiple />
</div>

<div ng-repeat="file in tab.namePRAttch.file track by $index">
  <a ng-src="{{file}}" ng-click="openImage(this)">{{file.name}}</a><i ng-click="removePRNameFile(file)" class="btn btn-md fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: To download binary data, use either `responseType: 'blob'` or `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`. For more info, see [MDN: XHR responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType).

Comment: if there is only blob data we can use the response type : 'blob'. But i have other few fields also for retrieving along with the blob data. i didn't mention that part. sorry.

Comment: My personal choice for including binary data in a JSON response is to use [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  For an example of posting binary files to an API which then returns a JSON response with the data encoded in base64, see [this DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/CqIixHWefjYmDfmJPbNF?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

To access the image you have to convert it into b64 format and for that make an entity and declare a variable imagePath as `String` type. Let the entity name be `ImagePath` assume you are getting a list from dao layer like `list = dao.getList`. Apply a for loop to access image and convert it to base64Binary like:
`String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(m.getImage());`
Inside the for loop instantiate your `ImagePath` entity and set the imagePath as `imagePath.setPath(b64);` along with all other attribute you wish to send with your image.
Now add it to you list `attbyArr.add(a);` and add it to your viewModel  `viewModel.setNamePRAttch(attbyArr);`

Let the *ImageClass* be:

```
@Entity
public class ImageClass implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4978144559787934722L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="image_id")
private int image_id;

@Lob
@Column(name="image_content", nullable=false, columnDefinition="mediumblob")
private byte[] image;  
}
```

Then *ImagePath Class* should be like:

```
public class ImagePath {

private int id;
private String imagePath;
} //generate getter setter and parametriced constructor
```

The *Controller Class* would have:

```
List<ImageClass> list = dao.getList();
List<ImagePath> imageList = new ArrayList<ImagePath>();
for (ImageClass m : list) {
        String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(m.getImage());
        ImagePath imagepath = new ImagePath();
        imagepath.setId(m.getImage_id());
        imagepath.setImagePath(b64);
        imageList .add(imagepath);
        model.addAttribute("imageList", imageList); //Or you can return it as a list that can be used in Angular
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I'm not very strong in serialization and all. Please explain imagepath thing.

Comment: @VishalRajendran I have edited my answer. Check this might help